# Combining ROCR performance objects

Tags: r

I have multiple `performance` objects created using `ROCR`. Each of these contain `auc` or `fpr/tpr` values for a class. In turn they have results for multiple test runs. So,

```
length(first.perf.obj@y.values)
```

gives something > 1.

I can plot average for a single class using

```
plot(first.perf.obj, avg="vertical")
```

as described in the ROCR manual. I want to combine these objects to calculate and plot their global average. Something like

```
global.perf.obj <- combine.perf.objects(first.perf.obj, second.perf.obj, third.perf.obj)
```

Is there an easy way to do this, or should I decompose each object and calculate values by hand?

Answer (score 0):

I went back recreating `prediction` objects for the global case.

I'm calling the `prediction` function like

```
global.prediction <- prediction(c(cls1.likelihood,
                                      cls2.likelihood,
                                      cls3.likelihood,
                                      cls4.likelihood,
                                      cls5.likelihood),
                                    c(duplicate.cols(cls1.labels, ncol(cls1.likelihood)),
                                      duplicate.cols(cls2.labels, ncol(cls2.likelihood)),
                                      duplicate.cols(cls3.labels, ncol(cls3.likelihood)),
                                      duplicate.cols(cls4.labels, ncol(cls4.likelihood)),
                                      duplicate.cols(cls5.labels, ncol(cls5.likelihood))),
                                    label.ordering=c(FALSE, TRUE))
```

for `duplicate.cols` simply builds a `data.frame` of repeating labels.

Then I'm able to get any statistic for the global case by e.g. `performance(global.prediction, "auc")`

It's a bit slow, but I think it's simpler than trying to combine values from multiple `performance` objects.